# Select only max mapname by country - sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to select only max mapname by country.  When I refer to "max mapname", I am referring to the value of "mapname" that appears the most times for that country. I am using Ms Sql Server.

This is the table structure for tblsurvey:

```
[country] [mapname]
    data:
    BR  MapQuest
    CA  OpenStreetMap
    CN  ArcGIS
    DE  Google Maps
    GR  Bing Maps
    IT  Google Maps
    US  Google Maps
    US  Bing Maps
    US  SAS.Planet
    US  Google Maps
```

query:

```
select country, mapname as mapnamemax
from tblsurvey s1
group by country, mapname
having count(mapname) = (select max(cnt)
                        from
                        (
                         select count(mapname) as cnt
                         from tblsurvey s2
                         where s1.country = s2.country and
                               s1.mapname = s2.mapname
                         group by mapname
                        )rc 
                        )
```

This is what I am currently getting (This is the current and incorrect query output)

```
current output:
CN  ArcGIS
GR  Bing Maps
US  Bing Maps
DE  Google Maps
IT  Google Maps
US  Google Maps
BR  MapQuest
CA  OpenStreetMap
US  SAS.Planet
```

This is what I would like to get. (This is the desired query output)

```
desired output:
BR  MapQuest
CA  OpenStreetMap
CN  ArcGIS
DE  Google Maps
GR  Bing Maps
IT  Google Maps
US  Google Maps
```

**Notes**: If there is a tie, then just return one row for that Country. The first one found

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks before hand.

Comment: You want to give us a hint as to what the structure and contents of the `tblsurvey` are?   Your question is fairly incomplete, seeing as we have no idea what the data is.

Comment: `I am trying to select only max by country`...max what?

Comment: See edited questions above, I have answered both questions requested by Lamak and LittleBobbyTables.

Comment: I think I get it now, for each country, you want to find out which `mapname` occurs the most (for example, US would be `Google Maps` since it occurs twice, one more than any other).  What about ties?

Comment: Wow you guys where quick to give me negative rating!  Are you humble enough to give me positive now that I have answered your questions?

Comment: @user3657279 - the question has had 19 views, who is to say who gave you the downvotes.  Besides, you still haven't answered all of our questions.   **What should the logic be about ties?  Do they both get returned?**

Comment: I am not saying it was you my friend.  What do you mean by "ties"?  Do you mean country then max amount of "mapname" value?

Comment: Yes; hypothetically, if there are two records for Google Maps and SAS.Planet for the US, I assume you would return both, but is that what you are expecting in that scenario?

Comment: I see what you mean, if there is a tie, then just return one.  The first one found.

Comment: The first one found *how*?  SQL records aren't ordered unless you *order them* with an ORDER BY statement.  You want the first one, alphabetically, to be returned?  Why wouldn't you return both in the case of a tie?

Comment: I will only be using one of the records if there is a tie.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way (in case of a tie, it returns one arbitrarily):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 
        A.country,
        B.mapname
FROM tblsurvey A
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 mapname
             FROM tblsurvey 
             WHERE country = A.country
             GROUP BY mapname
             ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) B
```

And [**here is**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/60a7b/2) a sqlfiddle with a demo.